# Stopping a subprocess when a specific string is found in the logs

Tags: python, ethereum

This is a question about subprocesses.

I'm working on using this asynchronous script for some of the work I'm doing: https://github.com/ethereum/trinity/blob/master/scripts/peer.py

The functionality of the script don't matter as much as the way I want to use this script.

Since it's asynchronous, I want to run it in a subprocess with different values, and for each subprocess, I want to wait for a certain timeout before I check for a string in the logs of the script. If I find the string I'm looking for, I exit the subprocess for that parameter passed, and pass in a new parameter, repeating the process.

From a high level, this is the subprocess script I'm trying out.

```
import subprocess
enode = 'enode://ecd3f3de6fc1a69fdbb459ccfeedb9ae4b@127.0.0.1:30303'

command = [
   'python',
   '-m',
   'scripts.peer',
   '-mainnet',
   '-enode',
   enode
]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    print(outs)
    print(errs)
```

This code doesn't work and never exits the script. How can I use subprocess with an async script so I can halt it when I grep for a value in the logs of the subprocess and that value I'm looking for is found there.

The string in the logs I'm looking for is: `failed DAO fork check validation` which I'd use as my trigger to stop the script.

Comment: Are you asking how to read the output of the subprocess until you see a certain message, then kill it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly set up the input and error streams of the subprocess to `subprocess.PIPE` to read from them, like so.

```
# ...
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: How would I be able to read and halt it when a certain string is found?